# window.print() not applying text color on dynamically generated text

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

In my application, I have used window.print() to make browser print a page. But it does not applying text color to some contents which are dynamically generated. In my case some contents are coming form database. I've put

```
@media print {
    .order-notes { 
        color: red !important;
    }
}
```

This code on top of the page in css block and it works fine for static contents. But when I apply same logic for dynamic contents, in my case contents are coming from mySQL database in the following format:

```
<div class="order-notes"> <?php echo $row['shipping_address']; ?></div>
```

Here window.print() not applying the text color to red.

Please help.

Comment: Than something is up with how you write the html to the page..... What is the generated source look like

Comment: It's actually a php file. Has style tag on top which contains all the print related css under @media print {} and inside body tag , contains data. It's basically an invoice page. There are static labels and dynamic contents coming form database. Thanks.

Comment: It is impossible for us to help you debug it.... We need to know what is spit out.